# Visual Stuiod Code Intellisense not working with React Native alias

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code, intellisense

My React Native project already has alias of some folder. They are put in `babel.config.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
    presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
    'plugins': [
        [
            'module-resolver',
            {
                'root': [
                    '.',
                ],
                'alias': {
                    'assets/*': './src/assets/*',
                    'images': './src/assets/images',
                    'navigation': './src/navigation',
                    'navigation/*': './src/navigation/*',
                    'screens': './src/screens',
                    'screens/*': './src/screens/*',
                    'splash': './src/modules/splash',
                    'utils': './src/utils',
                    'utils/*': './src/utils/*',
                    'translations': './src/utils/translations',
                    'translations/*': './src/utils/translations/*',
                    'msg': './src/utils/translations/msg',
                    'languages': './languages',
                    'styles': './src/styles',
                    'styles/*': './src/styles/*',
                    'components': './src/components',
                    'constant': './src/constant',
                    'context': './src/context',
                    'api': './src/API',
                    'store': './src/store',
                    'store/*': './src/store/*',
                },
            },
        ],
        'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
    ],
    'env': {
        'production': {
            'plugins': [
                'transform-remove-console',
            ],
        },
    },
};
```

But when I import a function using these alias, the intellisense does not work. I also try to create `jsonconfig.json` follow this document (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig)

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "paths": {
          "app/*": ["src/app/*"],
          "assets/*": ["src/assets/*"],
          "images": ["/src/assets/images"],
          "navigation": ["/src/navigation"],
          "navigation/*": ["/src/navigation/*"],
          "screens": ["/src/screens"],
          "screens/*": ["/src/screens/*"],
          "splash": ["/src/modules/splash"],
          "utils": ["/src/utils"],
          "utils/*": ["/src/utils/*"],
          "translations": ["/src/utils/translations"],
          "translations/*": ["/src/utils/translations/*"],
          "msg": ["/src/utils/translations/msg"],
          "languages": ["/languages"],
          "styles": ["/src/styles"],
          "styles/*": ["/src/styles/*"],
          "components": ["/src/components"],
          "constant": ["/src/constant"],
          "context": ["/src/context"],
          "api": ["/src/API"],
          "store": ["/src/store"],
          "store/*": ["/src/store/*"],
        }
    }
}
```

but still not working. Anyone can help me to fix the intellisense in VS Code?